# Single quote at then end is missing in create view in procedure

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a stored procedure where a string parameter need to be passed to a create a view, I am facing difficulty to enclose the string in single quotes

```
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
            'CREATE VIEW view_Exec_Data as
      Select * from Employees
            where exec_id='''' ||To_NChar(EID)||'''';  --EID is input parameter and value will be 9DE4D0106D1F390EE0
```

Above query is generated as

```
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
            'CREATE VIEW view_Exec_Data as
      Select * from Employees
            where exec_id='9DE4D0106D1F390EE0;
```

Single quote at the end is missing, not sure where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
            'CREATE VIEW view_Exec_Data as
      Select * from Employees
            where exec_id=To_NChar(''' || EID ||''')'; 
            --                     ^ 3 (')       ^ 3 + 1 (')
```

### Update

Working for me. See this:

```
SQL> set serverout on
SQL> declare
  2  EID varchar2(100) := '9DE4D0106D1F390EE0';
  3  begin
  4  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CREATE VIEW view_Exec_Data as
  5        Select * from Employees
  6              where exec_id=To_NChar(''' || EID ||''')');
  7  end;
  8  /
CREATE VIEW view_Exec_Data as
      Select * from Employees
            where
exec_id=To_NChar('9DE4D0106D1F390EE0')

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but still the same output, single quote at end is missing

Comment: still the same issue `To_NChar('9DE4D0106D1F390EE0 `

Answer (score 0):

We lack some info; for example, I wonder why you used `TO_NCHAR` ... do you *really* need it?

Here's an example which presumes that employees table looks like this:

```
SQL> create table employees (exec_id varchar2(30), name varchar2(30));

Table created.

SQL> insert into employees values ('9DE4D0106D1F390EE0', 'Littlefoot');

1 row created.

SQL> select * From employees;

EXEC_ID                        NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
9DE4D0106D1F390EE0             Littlefoot
```

A procedure which creates a view. I'd suggest **NOT** to do that. Do you really really want to have *zillion* views, one per each `EXEC_ID` someone uses as a parameter? What's the purpose of doing that? Why don't you simply

```
select * from employees where exec_id = :par_eid;
```

Anyway, here you go: in order to make that many single quotes simpler, I used `q-quoting mechanism`.

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_crv (par_eid in employees.exec_id%type)
  2  is
  3    l_str varchar2(200);
  4  begin
  5    l_str := q'[CREATE or replace VIEW view_Exec_Data as
  6                Select * from Employees
  7                where exec_id= to_nchar(']' || par_eid || q'[')]';
  8
  9    -- when using dynamic SQL, **ALWAYS** check whether command is properly written
 10    dbms_output.put_line(l_str);
 11
 12    -- if it looks OK, then execute it
 13    execute immediate l_str;
 14  end;
 15  /

Procedure created.

SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> exec p_crv('9DE4D0106D1F390EE0');
CREATE or replace VIEW view_Exec_Data as
              Select * from Employees

where exec_id= to_nchar('9DE4D0106D1F390EE0')

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * From view_exec_data;

EXEC_ID                        NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
9DE4D0106D1F390EE0             Littlefoot

SQL>
```

---

If you don't need `to_nchar`, it gets somewhat simpler:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_crv (par_eid in employees.exec_id%type)
  2  is
  3    l_str varchar2(200);
  4  begin
  5    l_str := q'[CREATE or replace VIEW view_Exec_Data as
  6                Select * from Employees
  7                where exec_id= ']' || par_eid || q'[']';
  8
  9    -- when using dynamic SQL, **ALWAYS** check whether command is properly written
 10    dbms_output.put_line(l_str);
 11
 12    -- if it looks OK, then execute it
 13    execute immediate l_str;
 14  end;
 15  /

Procedure created.

SQL> exec p_crv('9DE4D0106D1F390EE0');
CREATE or replace VIEW view_Exec_Data as
              Select * from Employees

where exec_id= '9DE4D0106D1F390EE0'

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * From view_exec_data;

EXEC_ID                        NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
9DE4D0106D1F390EE0             Littlefoot

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but code after `par_eid ` in the where clause is being skipped or ignored. any ideas?

Comment: You're welcome. No ideas, as I don't understand what you mean. How is it being skipped or ignored? It is not, at least not in my example ... could you explain it, please?

Comment: Ignored in the sense, closing quote and closing braces are being added to query, query is ending at `to_Nchar('9DE4D0106D1F390EE0`

Comment: Hm, it is not. Have a closer look at DBMS_OUTPUT result(s) in both of my examples. In the first one, that line is `where exec_id= to_nchar('9DE4D0106D1F390EE0')` so - nothing is missing. Please, edit the question by adding copy/paste of your own SQL*Plus session which shows what you did and how Oracle responded.

Comment: I am getting this output `ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement   `

Comment: I can't debug code I can't see. Code I posted *works*. If you did exactly like I did, it should work for you to. If it does not (apparently, it does not), then post code you used and I'll have a look.